# Upcoming columns after 16th auto replaced from next column value during importing Excel sheet

Tags: java, collections, apache-poi

> If i use less than 16 columns in excel sheet then its working fine.
>   But if columns size greater than 16 then 17th column value will change
>   with 16th and 18th with 19th  and so on.

Method is given below:-

```
protected Vector readExcelFile(String fileName) {
       /**
        * --Define a Vector --Holds Vectors Of Cells
   */
  Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();

  try{
  /** Creating Input Stream**/
  FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);

  /** Create a POIFSFileSystem object**/
  POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

  /** Create a workbook using the File System**/
   HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

   /** Get the first sheet from workbook**/
  HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

  /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
    Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

    while(rowIter.hasNext()){
        HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
        Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
        Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
        while(cellIter.hasNext()){
            HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
            cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell);
        }
        cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
    }
       } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
       }
  return cellVectorHolder;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you [read the Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) and follow the advice there?

Comment: Thanx Gagravarr for showing interest in this question. This issue was resolved after changing jar file version 2.5 to 3.1.4 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved after changing jar file version 2.5 to 3.1.4 .